# DB Data migration to new structure

Tags: sql, sql-server, data-migration

I need to migrate data from SQL Server 2008 Database to a new table structure. I'm currently doing it with SQL scripts.
Table structure looks like this:
[image: table structure]
I've tried to migrate data using this script:

```
INSERT INTO [NewCompanies]
       ([ID]
       ,[ApplicationID]
       ,[Name])          
 SELECT c.Id
        ,(SELECT ApplicationId 
            FROM [Files] f 
            WHERE f.CompanyId = c.Id 
            GROUP BY ApplicationId, CompanyId)
        ,c.Name      
 FROM [Companies] c
GO
```

But it's not working, because there are cases that same company belongs to more then 1 application in old db structure.
As a solution to this I need to insert one more record with same Name in the company table and use that CompanyId.

How can I acceive this with SQL script?
Here is [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1a762/8) that demonstrates the case.

Comment: umm, how about joining with [Files] instead of having it as a subquery-field?

Answer (score 0):

If the applicationID is always the same, you can just add "Top 1" into the subquery:

```
INSERT INTO [NewCompanies]
       ([ID]
       ,[ApplicationID]
       ,[Name])          
 SELECT c.Id
        ,(SELECT TOP 1 ApplicationId 
            FROM [Files] f 
            WHERE f.CompanyId = c.Id 
            GROUP BY ApplicationId, CompanyId)
        ,c.Name      
 FROM [Companies] c
GO
```

Comment: No, it's not the same, that's the problem. If I would use top 1 then I would assign all the companies to the same application. Instead I need to create  different Companies and assign them to different applications. So each new ApplicationId would result in new Company with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it this way:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[NewCompanies]
([ID],
 [ApplicationID],
 [Name]
)
       SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY name ASC) AS Row#,
              sq.ApplicationId,
              c.Name
       FROM
       (
           SELECT ApplicationId,
                  CompanyId
           FROM [Companies] c
                LEFT JOIN [Files] f ON c.Id = f.CompanyId
           GROUP BY ApplicationId,
                    CompanyId
       ) AS sq
       INNER JOIN Companies c ON sq.CompanyId = c.Id
       ORDER BY sq.CompanyId;
GO
```